# Root page loads, but when click on buttons, does not route

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, iron-router

Im using iron router v1+, with the below routes.

```
Router.configure({
   layoutTemplate    : 'layout',
   loadingTemplate   : 'loading',
   notFoundTemplate  : 'notFound',
   waitOn: function() {
      return [
         Meteor.subscribe('notifications')
      ];
   }
Router.route('/',          { name: 'root'});
Router.route('/login',     { name: 'login' });
Router.route('/register',  { name: 'register' });

Router.onBeforeAction(function(){
   if (! Meteor.user() && this.ready() ){
         Router.go('root');    
         console.log("login required"); 
      } else { 
         this.next();
      }                 
}, { 
   except: ['root', 'login', 'register'] 
});
```

**layout.html**

```
        {{#if currentUser}}
            {{> yield}}     
        {{else}}
            {{> root}}
        {{/if}}
```

**the root html**

```
<div>  <a href="{{pathFor route='login'}}"> Login </a> </div>
<div>  <a href="{{pathFor route='register'}}"> Signin </a> </div>
```

The issue is root page loads up, but when I click either the login or signup buttons, it does not route to the page.

Originally I wanted the landing page to be login page, but the page turns out blank. Currently the login and signup pages both only have a line of random comments each.

Comment: It's been some time since I used Iron Router (I have long switched to FlowRouter), but if memory serves you have to tell it what template you are using, right?  Otherwise, how would it know what template to show?  The `name` is just like a shortcut to be able to call `pathFor`, I thought.

Comment: @CodeChimp thanks for reply. Naming it alone should allow the route to work. (I have other routes that work on this basis). I tried adding template but still doesnt work. Once Im done with these, ill transit to flow router.

Comment: I assume the internals are that IR will try to look for a template with the same name as the `name` of the route, then?  Maybe the cases are different?  What happens if you enter an invalid router?

Comment: yeah IR guesses and routes to the closest name based on template name. cases are the same. invalid routes dont do anything. its hard to as theres no errors in console. I have no idea whats wrong. the url.../routename changes

Comment: What happens when you rename your "register" route to "root", basically forcing it to load register instead of your root.

Comment: still shows the root page when i swap them around

Comment: That's very strange.  That leads me to believe it's not IR that is the issue, but probably something else.  What happens if you alter your root template?  What about if you update the layout template?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117647/discussion-between-thinkerer-and-codechimp).

Comment: I keep getting this error 'Route dispatch never rendered. Did you forget to call this.next() in an onBeforeAction?' However I checked I only have 2 onbeforeactions ..and thye r all fine with 'this.next();